# Unable to connect repositories in openSUSE leap?

Tags: networking, opensuse, repository, yast

Unable to add Community repository  or refresh  repository in **openSUSE LEAP**
It isn't a problem with my network connection.

Here's the output when I open **yast**>>**online repositories**>>**refreshrepositories**

```
Download (curl) error for 'http://download.opensuse.org/…/…/non-oss/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed
Error message: Failed to connect to download.opensuse.org port 80: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answers.(Thanks to Forum member and g+community)

This problem because of cURL ,curl is using ipv6 for connection to your repositories so you need to configure curl to use ipv4.

we need to edit systl.conf file.

```
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
```

add following lines :-

```
 net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

 net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

 net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

also edit

```
sudo vi /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

replace **0** with **1**

and refresh repositories

```
sudo zypper refresh
```